Hartshorne Proposition II.7.6: Extended coherent sheaf generated by global sections
This is from the proof of the following proposition: Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme over $A$. and let $\mathscr{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Then $\mathscr{L}$ is ample if and only if $\mathscr{L}^m$ is very ample over Spec $A$ for some $m > 0$.
Let $\overline{X}$ be the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb P^n_A$. Now we can show a coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ extends to a coherent sheaf $\overline{F}$ in $\overline{X}$.
In the proof it is mentioned: Now given a coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$, it extends to a conherent sheaf $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ on $\overline{X}$. He says if  $\overline{\mathscr{F}}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}(\ell)$ is generated by global sections, then so is $\mathscr{F}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{{X}}(\ell)$.
Could someone explain why is so?

Ok I guess $\overline{\mathscr F}|X = \mathscr{F}$, so if $s_1\otimes 1,\cdots s_n\otimes 1$ generates $\overline{\mathscr{F}}\otimes \mathcal{O}{\overline{X}}(\ell)$, then $s_1\otimes 1,\cdots s_n\otimes 1$  generates ${\mathscr{F}}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{{X}}(\ell)$ as well. Is it right?

Yes, this is straightforward. It would be a good idea to either post your comment as an answer or delete the question.

alright, let me make this as an answer

Ok, so by definition $\overline{\mathscr F}|_X = \mathscr{F}$, so that suppose we have a set of global sections $s_1\otimes 1,\cdots s_n\otimes 1$ that generates $\overline{\mathscr{F}}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}(\ell)$, then their restrictions to $X\subseteq \overline{X}$, which would be given by $s_1|_X\otimes 1,\cdots s_n|_X\otimes 1$ would generate ${\mathscr{F}}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{{X}}(\ell)$. It was clear those were global sections of ${\mathscr{F}}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{{X}}(\ell)$, so this shows ${\mathscr{F}}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{{X}}(\ell)$ is generated by global sections.
